# Does the SRP suggest that an MVP Presenter should only have one responsibility?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have two features: one that presents the details of a single entity (`EntityX`) and one that allows the user to view a list of all EntityXs.

Using MVP, is it better to have an `EntityXController` with two methods (`View` and `List`, for example) that use the appropriate `View` and `List` views, or should I comply with my interpretation of the SRP and create an `EntityXListController` and an `EntityXViewController` to narrow the responsibilities of each?

Comment: You might get better answers on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds more like same Model, different View-Presenter for Details, and another View-Presenter for List.